# How to use PixelSearch() on inactive windows?

Tags: windows, pixel, autoit

Because of the `$hwnd` parameter I assume [`PixelSearch()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelSearch.htm) should work on an inactive window but I can't make it do so. When another window is put in front of the one to search, it fails.

My script :

```
$hwnd = WinGetHandle("[CLASS:MSPaintApp]")
$Cor = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth, @DesktopHeight, 0x39B6EF, 0, 1, $hwnd)
If Not @error Then
    MouseMove($Cor[0], $Cor[1])
Else
    MsgBox(0, "", @error)
EndIf
```

How can I make this work on an inactive window?

Comment: I don't think that you can use PixelSearch on something not shown on the screen.

Comment: What is your end goal here? It seems you are asking to search for something when the window isn't active? If this is correct, why?

Comment: @JonBecher, yes, and even it is not showing on the screen, like ControlSend and ControlClick. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix of making sure that the window you want to search on is active (If I read the question correctly). The `WinActive` checks to see if the window is active, and if it is 0 (not active). Then, we active the window using `WinActivate`.

```
Local $hwnd, $Cor
$hwnd = WinGetHandle("[CLASS:MSPaintApp]")
If WinActive($hwnd) = 0 Then
    WinActivate($hwnd)
EndIf
$Cor = PixelSearch(0, 0, @DesktopWidth, @DesktopHeight, 0x39B6EF, 0, 1, $hwnd)
If Not @error Then
    MouseMove($Cor[0], $Cor[1])
Else
    MsgBox(0, "", @error)
EndIf
```

Comment: I need to search when the window is not active so I can do something else while searching.

Comment: `Run("MSPaintApp", "", @SW_HIDE)` - That should allow you to have it hidden and still use it.

Comment: @JatSing Or use @SW_HIDE directly by setting the state of the window. [Here](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUISetState.htm) is the function reference for `GUISetState`.